# Formulario de búsqueda asp.net mvc ef

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, mvc, entity-framework, buscador

tengo este formulario de búsqueda, lo estoy haciendo en asp.net mvc utilizando entity framework, la idea es que el usuario seleccione al menos un dropdownlist y en la tabla le cargue los resulados, al hacer clic sobre alguno de los registros se abrirá la vista detalles de ese item. Los registros están guardados en sql server. Agradezco sugerencias de cómo podría realizar esto. Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma más sencilla de hacerlo (en mi opinión) es utilizando el ViewBag.

En el controller sería algo así

```
  //suponiendo que "db" es la variable que asignaste al EntityFramework.
    ViewBag.Marcas = db.Marcas.loList();
```

En el View, simplemente cargas los valores en un select

```
<select id="listaMarcas">
   @foreach (int element in ViewBag.Marcas)
   {
       <option value="@element.Id">@element.Nombre</option>    
   }
</select>
```

Para hacer el filtrado, necesitas hacer un post (cuando hagan clic en buscar) te recomiendo que leas este artículo en donde está todo muy claro.

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Que bien! Puedes votar por la respuesta ;)